# Running mySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with trying to run my mySQL query as a query in php:

This was the original mysql query:

```
SELECT *FROM clothing, sizing WHERE clothing.id = "101" AND sizing.type_id = clothing.type_id AND sizing.brand_id = clothing.brand_id;
```

I have tried editing it as the following:

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM clothing,sizing WHERE clothing.id = {$_GET['id']}") AND sizing.type_id = clothing.type_id AND sizing.brand_id = clothing.brand_id;
```

The code will only work when I do the following:

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM clothing,sizing WHERE clothing.id = {$_GET['id']}");
```

Is there a reason why this happens as I need to get it to display the full query on the second line?

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: You're closing your query prematurely with the `)` in `{$_GET['id']}")` in the 2nd example. And *"The code will only work when I do the following:"* so, use that instead (*perhaps*)? What's the issue/question/problem/other?

Comment: Fred, the working version trims the query after the first WHERE condition, so it does not include several of the query additional conditions which I suspect are required.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thanks George. Since the OP did say that the 3rd example worked (as stated by OP), then figured if it does work, then to use that one, and the 2nd example ending the query prematurely, he/she was probably asking the "why" it didn't work, which is why I pointed it out in my initial comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into an encapsulation issue. When you use a double-quote in the query itself, the PHP interpreter thinks you want to close the string that you started here:

```
query("SELECT
```

As a quick-and-dirty workaround, you can move the double-quote to the end of the string (instead of after `clothing.id = {$_GET['id']}`) to ensure that the string isn't closed prematurely.

```
$results = $connection->query(
    "SELECT * FROM clothing,sizing 
    WHERE clothing.id = {$_GET['id']})
    AND sizing.type_id = clothing.type_id 
    AND sizing.brand_id = clothing.brand_id;");
```

However, please be aware that you are at risk for an SQL injection attack since you are using untrusted user input in your query. Be sure to read about SQL injection vulnerabilities and consider using PDO for safer results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the reason is

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT * 
FROM clothing,sizing 
WHERE clothing.id = {$_GET['id']}")
AND sizing.type_id = clothing.type_id AND sizing.brand_id = clothing.brand_id;
```

is not correct you are using ) after `clothing.id = {$_GET['id']}"` and closing the query so it should be

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT * 
FROM clothing,sizing 
WHERE clothing.id = {$_GET['id']} 
AND sizing.type_id = clothing.type_id
AND sizing.brand_id = clothing.brand_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding query code outside the call to the query() function.  The query itself is surrounded by double quotes to indicate it's a string to be passed into the function, add your additional SQL fragment there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to use MySQL Query in php

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user_name","password","db_name"); \\ this is for creating connection.

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name"); \\ this is main query in php.
```